# Android: Show multiple street views (Google Maps Api)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-street-view

I have an xml file called activity_collage.xml with 2 street view fragments - I would like both fragments to display the street view of a given location - So a total of 2 street views on the screen

Here's my code:

```
public class Collage extends ActionBarActivity implements OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback {

StreetViewPanoramaFragment topLeft, topRight;

static final LatLng posOne = new LatLng(43.771925, -79.512460);

static final LatLng posTwo = new LatLng(43.790634, -79.193632);
```

Here's where I initialize my 2 StreetViewFragment objects in my onCreate() method

```
topLeft =
            (StreetViewPanoramaFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.picTL);
    topLeft.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(this);

    topRight =
            (StreetViewPanoramaFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.picTR);
```

Here's the overridden method from the OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback interface ...

```
@Override
public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama panorama) {
    panorama.setPosition(posOne);


}
```

But how do I set the street view for topRight?

Comment: in the same way ... just inside callback check if `panoram` belongs to `topRight` or `topLeft` fragment ...

Comment: naive way: `panorama.setTag("I'mAHappyPanoramaCheckWhichFragmentIsMyParent"); if(topRight.getView().findViewByTag("I'mAHappyPanoramaCheckWhichFragmentIsMyParent")!=null){ /*panorama is inside topRight*/} else {/*panorama is inside topLeft*/}`

Answer (score 1):

According to http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6953, multiple StreetViewPanorama Objects are not supported. In my experience, no explicit errors occur, but the second StreetViewPanorama will remain blank.

Frustratingly, I don't think the documentation was updated like the above thread indicates it should have been.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my fragment XML containing 2 fragments : map fragment, and StreetViewPanoramaFragment. StreetView stays blank. I managed to use it with a simple view instead of fragment.

With Kotlin it gives :

```
val myFrag=getView()!!.findViewById<StreetViewPanoramaView>(R.id.street_view_panorama)
    myFrag.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myFrag.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback { panorama ->
        panorama.setPosition(LatLng(55.758818, 37.620587))
        svPano = panorama
    })
```